# Spark CSV with various delimiters into DataSet

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have two **CSV files** that I am aggregating using spark with Java. These files have different delimeters.

file1.dat:

```
011!345!Ireland
```

files2.dat:

```
022Ç486ÇBrazil
```

Code I use:

```
Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false").option("delimeter", "\u00C7").option("delimeter", "!").load(logFile);
```

**Output:**

```
Error:Cannot resolve column name
```

If I remove one delimeter:

```
Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false").option("delimeter", "\u00C7").load(logFile);
```

**Output:**

```
Sno|code|Country
null|null|null 
022|486|Brazil
```

Is there a way to perform this?
Can both of these files be aggregated in the same spark code?

Comment: Note: `DataSet<Row>` is just a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple delimiters at the same time.

Instead, read the files separatly and use `union` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#union(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset))) to merge them together. For example:

```
Dataset<Row> people1 = spark.read()
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("delimeter", "!")
  .csv(logFile1);
Dataset<Row> people2 = spark.read()
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("delimeter", "\u00C7")
  .csv(logFile2);

Dataset<Row> people = people1.union(people2);
```

Comment: Would it make sense to read the whole file into one DF of "lines", then cache it, and then filter/parse + union it? I'm thinking the union may not be necessary if you parse the delimiters outside the `csv().option()`

Comment: @cricket_007 That would be another possible solution. I'm actually not sure which one would be better from a performance perspective but I think the above is easier to understand and look cleaner (since the delimiters are different for the files, if the same file had multiple delimiters then this answer would not work and it would be necessary to do the parsing manually).

Comment: If two files, then I agree... I was confused by the question showing `load(logFile)` twice.